# how to setup ios launchscreen.xib with LaunchImage in image.xcassets

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6.2 .  It now comes with a LaunchScreen.xib .  I also have a splash screen image in my image.xcassets.

Should I integrate the splash screen image into a imageview in the xib file?  I tried this, and it does not let me put that image file in the interface builder.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was the best way, but I actually removed the LaunchScreen.xib file from my project and indicated the Launch Images Source to be the LaunchImage within the images.xcassets folder. I even removed the LaunchScreen from the Launch Screen File and it works how I want it to now.

Image below is from my project's target General tab.

[image]

Comment: When uploading build for iOS 9 you can't do it any more (multitasking requires LaunchScreen.xib).

Answer (score 0):

Launch image is basically needed for devices before iOS 7.1 and launch nib is new feature in devices after that.So I put launch images and launch nib both in my project

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6 allows use a LaunchScreen.xib for iOS8+. It the best way to create a launch screen if your app:

- Support only iOS8+, previous version need a launch image source.
- If your launch screen is simple and you can get it using UILabel or other UI objects supported in launch screen xib.

Why use LaunchScreen.xib? Because you can support all the screen devices with one file if you setup the auto layout properly. And believe me, it's great if you're coding a universal app.

If your launch screen has a more complex design (logos, custom typography...) you'll have to use launch images sources and you'll have to create one image for every screen sizes.